# Does not iterate through the class that implement Iterable

Tags: java, loops, iterator, iteration, iterable

The code below gives me the does not compile giving me the following error: "foreach not applicable to type 'Bag<\java.lang.Integer>'".

I don't understand where is the problem because the "Bag" class is implementing "Iterable" so, I guess, the loop should treat the "Bag" as an "Iterable". Please, can you clarify the situation for me?

```
class Bag<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
private Node first;

private class Node {
    Item item;
    Node next;
}

public void add(Item item) {
    Node oldfirst = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.item = item;
    first.next = oldfirst;
}

public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    return new ListIterator();
}

private class ListIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
    private Node current = first;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return current != null;
    }

    public void remove() {}

    public Item next() {
        Item item = current.item;
        current = current.next;
        return item;
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bag<Integer> a = new Bag();
    a.add(5);
    a.add(10);
    for (int w : a) {
        System.out.println(w.iterator());
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Where does Bag come from? If it does not compile it cannot implement Iterable.

Comment: Actually [**it works**](https://ideone.com/cBFM83) for me

Answer (score 2):

The problems were in your `main` method. After few simple fixes this works:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bag<Integer> a = new Bag<>();
    a.add(5);
    a.add(10);
    for (int w : a) {
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

First of, `Bag` initialization - `<>` was missing, didn't compile for me without it.

Then in the println, you can't call `w.iterator()` because `w` is an `int` which doesnt have such method. Not sure what you wanted to achieve with that there.

Comment: Yeah, I sort of knew that I can not iterate through Integer. I was just messing with things to understand why this is not working and forgot to rechange w.iterator() to w while posting the question. However, the problem in my case is in the loop itself. While writing for (int w : a) it gives the error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bag<Integer> a = new Bag();
    a.add(5);
    a.add(10);
    for (int w : a) {
        System.out.println(w);
    }
}
```

You can not iterate integer. its is used to iterate collection. You just need to change             System.out.println(w);

And if you are in java 8
Then you can directly iterate using

```
a.iterator().forEachRemaining(n -> System.out.println(n));
```